# Asymptotics of Laplace transform for small parameter

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

The context of the question is that I was trying to derive the asymptotics of the modified Bessel function of the second kind:
$$ K_\alpha(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-z\cosh(t)}\cosh(\alpha t)dt $$
for $z$ small, which Wikipedia gives as
$$ K_\alpha(z) \sim \begin{cases} -\log(z/2) - \gamma, &\alpha = 0, \\ 
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{2}(2/z)^\alpha, &\alpha > 0. \end{cases} $$

My attempt is to make a change of variable $x = \cosh(t)$ so that $t = \text{arccosh}(x)$ and $dx = \sinh(t)dt$ so that
$$ K_\alpha(z) = \int_1^\infty e^{-zx}\cosh(\alpha\,\text{arccosh}(x))\frac{dx}{\sinh(\text{arccosh}(x))}. $$
If $\alpha = 0$ for simplicity say then $\sinh(\text{arccosh}(x)) = \sqrt{x^2-1}$ so making another substitution $x = y + 1$ we obtain
$$ K_0(z) = e^{-z} \int_0^\infty e^{-zy} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y(y+2)}} $$
which I recognise as a Laplace transform. How does one proceed from here to obtain (either the $\alpha = 0$ case or the general case) asymptotics for $K_0(z)$ as $z \rightarrow 0^+$? (Is this even the right approach?)

In general is there a way to study the asymptotics of the Laplace transform $\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}f(t)dt$ for $z \rightarrow 0^+$? I'm asking this question since most answers I've found seem to relate to asymptotics as $z \rightarrow \infty$ and I'm also interested in a more general discussion of techniques to study asymptotics of integrals of this form.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151936/modified-bessel-function-near-zero/4151966#4151966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the case $\alpha=0$ first.
$$K_0(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-z\cosh t}dt$$
Making the substitution $x=\cosh t$
$$K_0=\int_1^\infty e^{-zx}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=e^{-z}\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t+2}\sqrt t}=2e^{-z}\int_0^\infty e^{-2zx^2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Using $d\big(\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})\big)=\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ and integrating by part (also making several substitutions)
$$K_0=2e^{-z}e^{-2zt^2}\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})\Big|_{t=0}^\infty+8ze^{-z}\int_0^\infty e^{-2zt^2}\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})tdt$$
$$=2e^{-z}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln\frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+2z}}{\sqrt{2z}}dx=-e^{-z}\ln(2z)+2e^{-z}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+2z})dx$$
In the second integral the main contribution comes from the region $x>z$.
Indeed,
$$|\int_0^{2z} e^{-x}\ln(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+2z})dx|<|\int_0^{2z}\ln(\sqrt {2z})dx|<|\int_0^{2z}\ln(\sqrt {2x})dx|=O(z\ln z)\ll1$$
Therefore, to find the main asymptotics term, we can drop $2z$ in the second integral and (with the required accuracy) integrate from zero to $\infty$. Also, $e^{-z}=1+O(z)\sim 1$. Taking all together
$$K_0\sim-\ln(2z)+2\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln(2\sqrt x)dx=-\ln(2z)+2\ln2+\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln xdx$$
$$K_0\sim \ln\frac{2}{z}-\gamma$$
For $\alpha> 0$ we are acting in the same way.
$$K_\alpha(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-z\cosh(t)}\cosh(\alpha t)dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-z-x}\cosh\Big(\alpha\cosh^{-1}(1+\frac{x}{z})\Big)}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+2z}}dx$$
Using $\cosh^{-1}(a)=\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$ (we consider $x>0$), after easy transformations we get
$$K_\alpha(z)=\frac{e^{-z}}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx\,e^{-x}}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+2z}}\bigg(\Big(1+\frac{x}{z}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{2x}{z}}\,\,\Big)^\alpha+\Big(1+\frac{x}{z}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{2x}{z}}\,\,\Big)^{-\alpha}\bigg)$$
Again, the main contribution to the integral comes from the region $x>z$
$$\int_0^{2z}\frac{dx\,e^{-x}}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+2z}}\bigg(\Big(1+\frac{x}{z}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{2x}{z}}\,\,\Big)^\alpha+\Big(1+\frac{x}{z}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{2x}{z}}\,\,\Big)^{-\alpha}\bigg)$$
$$<\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2z}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+2z}}\Big((2+\sqrt3)^\alpha+1\Big)<\frac{(2+\sqrt3)^\alpha+1}{2\sqrt{2z}}\int_0^{2z}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=O(1)$$
Therefore, keeping the main terms ($\frac{x}{z}>1$) in the integrand, we get the main asymptotics term:
$$K_\alpha(z)\sim\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}\big(2\frac{x}{z}\big)^\alpha}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{2}{z}\Big)^\alpha\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{2}\Big(\frac{2}{z}\Big)^\alpha\gg1$$

Comment: Thanks for showing all the steps - I think I get the general idea and can probably apply it to the application I'm interested in.

Comment: @Riley Thank you for your comment. I used the heuristic approach - this is not the rigorous proof. The underlying idea is to evaluate the contribution of different intervals of integration to the integral value and to keep only the most important terms in the integrand. Usually it works :)